# manipulation of request into javascript ajax for laravel api

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, request

I am trying to execute form submission into laravel, but the problem is i had to go through the javascript while submitting the form for processing the table data. I wanted a guidance regarding the detailed execution into my case. Is it possible to add more fields into the request before submitting the request to the laravel api. for more clarification please check the image i have attached. Also sharing the code below.

[Graphical Presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBM9Z.png)

Currently Using code snippet.

**Webpage.php snippet**

```
        <form id="userForm" name="userForm" method="POST"
            action=" {{ url('/submit_user_form')}} ">

                  <input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is- 
                  invalid @enderror" name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" required 
                  autocomplete="first_name" autofocus>

                  <input id="last_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('last_name') is- 
                  invalid @enderror" name="last_name" value="{{ old('last_name') }}" required 
                  autocomplete="last_name" autofocus>

            <button style="width:100%; margin-bottom:30px" type="submit" id="BtnSubmitUserForm" 
            name="BtnSubmitUserForm" class="btn btn-primary">
       </form>
```

**Javascript snippet**

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">

         $('#userForm').submit(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
           var last_name= $('#last_name').val();

           // i want to add more field here into the request. before submitting the form
           document.getElementById("userForm").submit();
         });

    </script>
```

Comment: You can add hidden fields into the form and with the JS code insert values on the fields and then submit

Comment: @Trouner its very very difficult to fetch data from tables. Hence this way to be used.

Comment: can you explain that more? where is the information you want to add?

Comment: @Trouner for example my request has 3 fields originally and then i want to add two more fields into the request and pass it to the api.